# Trying to calculate the time to execute instructions of a five-stage Pipeline processor

Tags: mips, pipeline

Suppose if M5 is a **five-stage pipelined implementation**.

I know that the five-stage pipeline has following steps:

```
    IF -- instruction fetch (and PC update)
    ID -- instruction decode (and get operands from registers)
    EX -- ALU operation (can be effective address calculation)
    MA -- memory access
    WB -- write back (results written to register(s))
```

If suppose there are 100 MIPS instructions with the following
instruction mix:

```
Loads 23%, Stores 12%, Conditional Branches 12%, Jumps
8% and R-type instructions 45%.

The CPU clock frequency is 1.2 GHz
```

I am trying to calculate the time to execute the 100 instructions. I understand how to calculate the time for a non-pipeline using this formula

```
ExTime = Instruction count * CPI * Clock period in seconds
```

I convert the frequency to period using `1/f = 8.33 * 10^-10 seconds`
But I am unsure of a way to calculate the execution time for this pipeline and do I need to know the cycles of the pipeline implementation?

Please help me out as I can't find a decent example online.
Thanks

**EDIT**

I think I have found the answer!

I found some information that

```
INSTRUCTION LATENCY = 5 time units THEREFORE
INSTRUCTION THROUGHPUT = 5 * (1 / 5) = 1 instruction per time unit
So in this case it would be: 
ExTime in seconds = Number of instructions * clock cycle period in seconds
```

Comment: I dont see why I should be getting a -1? Care to explain?

Comment: You also need to take into account the pipeline flushes on branches and jumps.

Comment: So how would you go on calculating it then?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the time taken by flushes on branches/jumps:

Average no of cycles taken by an instruction in the given instruction mix =

(0.23)*5 + (0.12)*4 + (0.12)*4 + (0.08)*4 + (0.45)*4 = 4.23 clock cycles

(Load takes 5 cycles, Store: 4, R: 4, Jump/Branch: 4)

Now,

No of cycles taken by 1 instruction at an average = 4.23

=> No of cycles taken by 100 instructions at an average = 423

Clock frequency = 1.2Ghz

=> Time taken for 1 cycle = 8.33 * 10^-10

=> Time taken for 423 cycles = 3.5236 * 10^-7 = Ans